# Most recent year and project per municipality

Tags: mysql

I have got two tables. One with municipalities (`wsjg_mun`) and another one with projects (`wsjg_proj`). I need the most recent year (`yr`) and project (`proj_id`) per municipality.

```
Table wsjg_mun (municipalities)

    pol_id (hash version of municipality name)
    mun (municipality name)
    cbs_cde
    cbs_id (municipality id, PK)

Table wsjg_proj (projects)

    cbs_id (municipality id)
    yr (year project)
    edition
    proj_id (project)
    lud
```

This query

```
SELECT a.pol_id, a.mun, a.cbs_cde, a.cbs_id,  yr, b.edition FROM wsjg_proj b   
LEFT JOIN wsjg_mun a 
ON a.cbs_id = b.cbs_id
GROUP BY b.cbs_id, b.yr
ORDER BY  b.cbs_id , b.yr asc
```

Results in:

```
Bedum     2010  BP
Bedum     2011  BR
Bedum     2014  BP  
Ten Boer  2011  BR
Ten Boer  2013  BP
```

I would like to have

```
Bedum     2014  BP  
Ten Boer  2013  BP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a query like this will be useful:

```
SELECT a.mun, b.yr, b.edition
FROM wsjg_mun a
  LEFT JOIN wsjg_proj b ON a.cbs_id = b.cbd_id
WHERE b.yr = (
        SELECT Max(bi.yr) 
        FROM wsjg_proj bi
        WHERE bi.cbs_id = b.cbs_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you provided as an example doesn't match the query, but anyway i would think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
select a.mun, b.edition, b.yr
from wsjg_mun a 
join wsjg_proj b on a.cbs_id = b.cbs_id
join (
    select cbs_id, max(yr) as max_yr
    from wsjg_proj
    group by cbs_id
) max_proj_yr on b.cbs_id = max_proj_yr.cbs_id and max_proj_yr.max_yr = b.yr
```

The query used as a derived table determines the latest year for each cbs_id.